# Am I safe from thread pool starvation/socket issues if I use Flurl in a service thats registered as Transient?

Tags: c#, flurl

Let's say I have a simple service that's registered as a `Transient` in `Startup`, and I use Flurl like so:

```
public async Task DoStuff()
    {
        string url = "some valid Url";
        await url
            .AppendPathSegment("notifications")
            .WithHeader("a header", headervalue1)
            .WithHeader("another header", headervalue2)
            .PostJsonAsync(data);
    }
```

This service will be used a lot throughout our app. Can I count on Flurl to handle the requests efficiently so that my app doesn't exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads?

Comment: Just as a side note (the accepted answer is correct), you get this behavior "for free" only when you follow the pattern where you "start" with a URL like you've done. If you choose to use FlurlClient [explicitly](https://flurl.dev/docs/client-lifetime/#managing-instances-explicitly), you're on your own like you would be with raw HttpClient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [their docs](https://flurl.dev/docs/client-lifetime/): yes - the default usage, as you are showing, makes uses of the implementation guidelines provided by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0#remarks):

*Quote:*

> Flurl.Http is built on top of the System.Net.Http stack. If you're familiar with HttpClient, you probably already know this [advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0#remarks):
>
> > HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Especially in server applications, creating a new HttpClient instance for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors.

> Flurl.Http adheres to this guidance by default. Fluent methods like this will create an HttpClient lazily, cache it, and reuse it for every call to the same host*:

Sources:

https://flurl.dev/docs/client-lifetime/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0#remarks

---

Keep in mind though - "heavy load" can still mean you'll hit certain limits like:

- reaching maximum server connections - i.e.: possible server overload
- reaching maximum client socket usage - i.e.: initiating too many concurrent connections

For more info see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=net-6.0

This means you'll still need to do a sanity check on the amount of connections you'll be expecting.